# How to listen to change of ChangeNotifier inner plane object property?

Tags: flutter, dart

I using Provider.
for example

```
class MyModel(){
  int foo;
  String bar = 'baaaa';
}

class MyScreenViewModel() with ChangeNotifier{
MyModel myModel = MyModel();
}


class MyScreen(){
//...something
  ChangeNotifierProvider{
    Text('$provider.myModel.bar')
    Buttone(onTap =>  provider.myModel.bar = 'bbbbbb')
  }
}
```

It's not work.
so I added some method at MyScreenViewModel

```
changeBar(String str){
  myModel.bar = str; 
  notifyListeners(); 
}
```

It's only way to listen to change inner Object property?

I'm looking for like this

```
class MyScreenViewModel() with ChangeNotifier{
  MyModel myModel = MyModel();
  myModel.addListener();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to user `notifyListeners();` every time you want tell your widgets that your model changed, so they will update themselves (that's very simple explanation).

Learn how to use `Provider` with `ChangeNotifierProvider` and `Consumer`, then you just need to use `notifyListeners();`, there's lots of good material online, just take a good read.

All the code you provided doesn't make any sense, so I am thinking about it as pseudocode.